# php - Breadcrumb not displaying one of tab

Tags: php, breadcrumbs

Stated code unable to display following tab tab....

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">';
echo'  <a style="color: #999999" href=/brand/'; 
echo $info['brand_url']; 
echo' itemprop="url" title="Top Brand"><span itemprop="title">'; 
echo $info['brand_name']; 
echo'</span></a><span>&raquo;</span></div>
```

**i know what is the problem with the code...but have no idea how to rectify it...**

If i change `$info['brand_url'] //contains "Topman"` to just any data like `echo "Topman";`. it works fine....

Please tell me how i can do that.

thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Is this the actual code you're using?

Comment: yes this is one of breadcrumb.....

Comment: the question is that why it works when i just put echo "any value"; and does not work when i fetch data from database.

Comment: This question can't really be answered without seeing more of the code. My assumption would be that $info array doesn't have all the values in it that you think it does. Run die(print_r($info)); and post the results here - that way we'll know that brand_url exists.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the brand URL, but your last echo statement isn't closed, and there is no echo at the beginning. Maybe try a var_dump($brand) to ensure $brand['url'] is what you think it is

Comment: The problem is more likely to do with where the data is fetched from the database. Are you sure that $info contains the data you're looking for? Do you get any errors? what do you get if you var_export($info);?

Comment: there is no error i am getting data exactly as i want in website ....but when i test it on Rich Snippets tool...its show empty......even some of my page also indexed out it..

Comment: but interesting when i use....ucwords() its works fine...but i already set lowercase in htaccess...can't do it in this way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reorganize your code and fix lots of bugs. So what i got finally:

```
// Just some example data
$info['brand_url'] = 'Topman';
$info['brand_name']= 'Link title'; 

echo '<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">';
echo '  <a style="color: #999999" href="/brand/'; 
echo $info['brand_url'].'"'; 
echo ' itemprop="url" title="Top Brand"><span itemprop="title">'; 
echo $info['brand_name']; 
echo '</span></a><span>&raquo;</span></div>';



// Received output:
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"> 
    <a style="color: #999999" href="/brand/Topman" itemprop="url" title="Top Brand">
        <span itemprop="title">Link title</span>
    </a>
    <span>&raquo;</span>
</div>
```

P.S. If your code still dont work, so check your `$info['brand_url']` variable by var_dump() (or etc.) and make us sure again it rly contains "Topman".